# Are there any statistics on union endorsements for presidential candidates?

Tags: united-states, primaries, democratic-party, labor-union, endorsement

LA Times [mentioned a few](https://www.latimes.com/politics/story/2019-11-16/kamala-harris-bernie-sanders-labor-endorsements), seemingly mostly for Sanders by the big-membership numbers

> On Thursday, United Teachers Los Angeles, the second-largest teacher’s union in the U.S., with roughly 34,000 members, threw its support behind the Vermont senator.
>
> On Friday, Sanders joined representatives from the National Nurses United local office in Oakland to officially accept their endorsement. The union has more than 150,000 members nationwide.

The article also mentioned that this is a change since 2016 in some ways:

> Labor unions have been wary about making endorsements after their early backing of Hillary Clinton in the 2016 presidential election caused rifts in some major unions between leadership and the rank and file.

It also mentioned that Kamala Harris has picked up an endorsement from a smaller union.

But how is the union tally looking so far? Is Sanders by far the leader in this respect?

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any statistics on union endorsements for presidential candidates?

Lists of endorsements are maintained on Wikipedia: [Endorsements in the 2020 Democratic Party presidential primaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorsements_in_the_2020_Democratic_Party_presidential_primaries), and some candidates' separate endorsements pages. Some unions have endorsed multiple candidates.

As of 4 March 2020,

- [Joe Biden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Joe_Biden_2020_presidential_campaign_endorsements#Labor_unions): 7 unions.
- [Bernie Sanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bernie_Sanders_2020_presidential_campaign_endorsements#Labor_organizations): 6 national unions, 16 locals.
- [Elizabeth Warren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Elizabeth_Warren_2020_presidential_campaign_endorsements#Labor_unions): 2 unions.
- Tulsi Gabbard: 0 unions.
- Michael Bloomberg: 0 unions.
- Tom Steyer: 0 unions.